# Why are AWS SNS Topic Name have bigger character limit(256) than SQS Queue Name(80)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We are trying to create an application using SNS + SQS as our pub/sub.

However, as development continues we noticed we are having a hard time tracing the sns + sqs mappings, hence, the standardized pattern of creating sns topic name and sqs queue name but we find it weird that sqs queue names have lower character limit than sns topic name.

SNS Topic Name:

```
<appName>-<environment>-<topicName>
```

SQS Queue Name: the reason for this is for us to immediately know what topic the queue is subscribed to

```
<appName>-<environment>-<topicName>-<queueNameSubscribedToTopic>
```

SQS Queues will always have longer names than sns topic name. We might be missing something here on why AWS dedicated higher character limit of SNS Topic Names than SQS Queue names